# Woocommerce how to write or increment to existing rows in database

Tags: php, database, woocommerce

I have the following array

```
[0] => Array (
        [product_id] => 11
        [product_variation] => 0
        [product_count] => 1
    )

[1] => Array (
        [product_id] => 14
        [product_variation] => 18
        [product_count] => 3
    )

[2] => Array (
        [product_id] => 14
        [product_variation] => 18
        [product_count] => 1
    )
```

Now I want to write this to my database and create clean rows of data. If the `product_variation` is '0' that means the product is not a variable product. I want to write that to a database row that matches the `product_id` and increase the `product_count` in the database accordingly. If the `product_variation` is not '0' it increase the count in a row that matches the `product_variation`.

So the end result would contain two rows in my database:

```
product_id || product_variation || product_count
11            0                    1
14            18                   4
```

So far I got:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$database_orders = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_custom_orders");
$products = array();

//some code to fill $products

foreach ( $products as $product ){
    if ($product['product_variation'] == '0' ) {
        //write to product row where variation is the same
    } else {
        //write to product row where id is the same
    }
}
?>
```

Now I know about the simple insert/update functions already available and queries using sql but I am not sure how to verify if something already exists in the database and adjust a number properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you  have a unique ID row in your DB? Otherwise, I think you will need to query the DB to find a match by product or variation ID.

Comment: No the ID is not unique because products with a variable id can share the product ID

Comment: Yes, I know that. I am asking if you have a column for a unique identifying key specifically since product ID is *not* necessarily unique. If you did it would be possible to identify an existing row. It may also be possible to use a single ID (variation OR product depending ) as that would be unique.

Comment: Otherwise I think you will have to query for existing rows first. `$database_orders = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_custom_orders where product_id=%d", $product_id ) );` and even then it is probably hard to update the row without some kind of unique identifier.

Comment: My bad, I completely misread that. Yes I do have a unique ID collumn. And that's a good point. I do have one concern. Would it be good practice to make all these querries in a loop for all the products? I expect it to contain 20-50 product each use.